# Inserting an item in a Tuple

Tags: python, insert, tuples

Yes, I understand tuples are immutable but the situation is such that I need to insert an extra value into each tuple. So one of the items is the amount, I need to add a new item next to it in a different currency, like so:

```
('Product', '500.00', '1200.00')
```

Possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to functional programming.  You're not `updating` a tuple, you're creating a new tuple from an old tuple.  Use `collections.namedtuple` and it will be obvious that your're creating a new type of object from an old type of object.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can cast it to a list, insert the item, then cast it back to a tuple.

```
a = ('Product', '500.00', '1200.00')
a = list(a)
a.insert(3, 'foobar')
a = tuple(a)
print a

>> ('Product', '500.00', '1200.00', 'foobar')
```

Comment: Or any of a number of approaches that don't modify the original tuple, but replace it instead.

Comment: This really is not a good solution. You can just use `+= ('foobar',) ` for the same affect.

Comment: in python 3.8 it will give error.

Answer (score 64):

Since tuples are immutable, this will result in a new tuple. Just place it back where you got the old one.

```
sometuple + (someitem,)
```

Answer (score 24):

You absolutely need to make a new tuple -- then you can rebind the name (or whatever reference[s]) from the old tuple to the new one.  The `+=` operator can help (if there was only one reference to the old tuple), e.g.:

```
thetup += ('1200.00',)
```

does the appending and rebinding in one fell swoop.

Comment: yes, as i learned the hard way :P += does not attempt to modify the reference in place, it reassigns

Comment: @Matt, exactly -- but with a tuple or string, that's all you can do (if you apply it to a list, it _does_ modify it in-place -- the "reassign" part is a negligible overhead),

Comment: Always gets my hackles up. += in my mind should be an in-place modification. If you can't do it, don't appear to be doing it. I'm not the Python spec though, and clearly whatever my opinion, it does what it's defined to do. And it's not an objectively sane complaint anyway - integers are mutable and you can += them easy enough, which again means replacement. Basically intuition-clash between language models.

Comment: Oops - integers are *immutable* of course.

Comment: @Steve314, if you can do `i+=j` where `i` is immutable by being an `int`, it's clearly irrational to rant against being able to do it when it's immutable by being another type on which `+` is defined.

Comment: In C++ you can + a const int, but not += a const int. I *said* I was being irrational (or rather "not objectively sane"), and I also said "intuition-clash between language models". And no-ones ranting - I was simply commenting. Though I may well have been ranting in the past when we had a related discussion on comp.lang.python.

Answer (score 20):

```
def tuple_insert(tup,pos,ele):
    tup = tup[:pos]+(ele,)+tup[pos:]
    return tup

tuple_insert(tup,pos,9999)
```

**tup: tuple

pos: Position to insert

ele: Element to insert**

Answer (score 12):

For the case where you are not adding to the end of the tuple

```
>>> a=(1,2,3,5,6)
>>> a=a[:3]+(4,)+a[3:]
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can code simply like this as well:

```
T += (new_element,)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
t = (1,2,3,4,5)

t= t + (6,7)
```

output :

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Answer (score 4):

one way is to convert it to list

```
>>> b=list(mytuple)
>>> b.append("something")
>>> a=tuple(b)
```