# Adding values from loop to a tuple results in nested tuples instead of a flat tuple or list

Tags: python

I'm trying to perform the following:

```
tup1 = ()
for i in range(1, 10, 2):
    tup1 = (tup1, i)
print tup1
```

I expect the output to be the sequence 1 to 10.
However, I end up with the following:

```
((((((), 0), 2), 4), 6), 8)
```

What would be a correct way to meet the requirement?

Comment: if you just want the sequence from 1-10, just have somethign like `print(list(range(1,11)))`

Comment: Okay, but what are you actually trying to *do*?

Comment: I hope that you are aware that Tuples are immutable and are not supposed to be changed

Comment: True.. could have done that..
However the objective is to append the values to the tuple/list and then print the output...

Comment: @RNar what's the difference between `range(1,11)` and `list(range(1,11))`?

Comment: @abhisheknair if that is the case, then what you are doing wrong is you are making nested tuples instead of  concatenating tuples. you should instead have `tup1 = tup1 + (i,)` to set `tup1` as a new tuple that consists of itself and and the new item in the form of a single item tuple

Comment: @PierreLafortune, range(1,11) returns a range object. try printing it and you'll see what i mean

Comment: @RNar They both print the same output `print range(1,11) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and `print list(range(1,11)) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: Thanks RNar!
Could you please elaborate in detail on how it works ?

Comment: @RNar I think you're talking about `xrange`

Comment: @Mr.E, nope i am not. try running this line `print(range(1,11))` and you will see what i mean (at least in python 3)

Comment: By the way this question is duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309329/inserting-an-item-in-a-tuple

Comment: @abhisheknair, both otrebor and Tomasz have posted answers with concatenating tuples

Comment: @RNar except tomaz just edited to include the tuple concatenation which is an identical copy of Ortrebors answer 5 mins ago

Comment: @PierreLafortune and Mr. E, i apologize for the confusion, i am using python 3 not python 2! that is my bad

Comment: @RNar Well you're right in Python 3, in Python 2 it returns a list. Weird change there. Don't worry, it happens, I learned something new about ranges :D

Comment: @Mr.E and python 3 is the future so best to code with that in mind :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you just want an iterable with the even numbers 1 to 10 then the simplest way to do it:

```
seq = range(2, 11, 2)
```

If you are doing this as a means of learning Python and you want to build up your own data structure, use a list:

```
l = []
for i in range(2, 11, 2):
    l.append(i)
```

The above for loop can be rewritten as a list comprehension:

```
l = [i for i in range(2, 11, 2)]
```

or using an if clause in the loop comprehension:

```
l = [ i for i in range(1, 11) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: List comprehension is the way to go here. Tuples are immutable and not supposed to be changed / concatenated. so +1 for that and the pythonic way to do it :)

Answer (score 6):

You can append an item to a tuple using the `+=` operator.

```
tup1=()
for i in range(1,10,2):
   tup1+= (i,)
print tup1
```

This prints `(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)`

Answer (score 3):

Read about [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
tuple(i for i in range(1, 10, 2))
```

Or

```
tup1 = ()
for i in range(1, 10, 2):
 tup1 += (i,)
print tup1
```

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are immutable objects in Python. Thus means you can't modify them. What you're doing right now is creating a new tuple with the previous one inside

You could do:

```
lst = []
for i in range(1,10,2):
  lst.append(i)
tup = tuple(lst) #If you really want a tuple
print tup
```

But `lst = range(1,10,2)` or `tup = tuple(range(1,10,2))` is much better (Unless you want to use append for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

it's something like this:

```
print range(1, 11)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about the output of your command. Also, the question might no target to create a specific ordered range, but how to concatenate several values in a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping by two by using `for i in range(1,10,2):` if you use `for i in range(1,11):` if will increment by 1. As for `tup1=(tup1,i)` you are constantly adding a tuple to each other which is creating the weird output. You could use a list if you want to store them. Otherwise using will do it just fine:

```
print(range(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

List item

For appending into list or tuple you can use append() function or you can use += operator which does the same.
s=()

## for sequence of numbers from 1 to 10

for i in range(1,11):
    s+=(i,)

print(s)  #(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

## for sequence of numbers from 1 to 10 with step size 2

x=()

for i in range(1,11,2):
    x+=(i,)

print(x)   #odd nos from 1-9 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)

x=()

for i in range(2,11,2):
    x+=(i,)

print(x) #even nos from 2-10  (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)

- List item

Answer (score 0):

Storing values from loop in a list or tuple in Python by following ways -

-> By appending the value in the list (here new_data1) as join will not work here.

```
new_data1 = []
for line in all_words:
    new_data=' '.join(lemmatize_sentence(line))
    new_data1.append(new_data)
    #print (new_data)
print (new_data1)
```

P.S. -  This is just a snapshot of a code just for hint .
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
lst = []  # Create an Empty list
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    lst.append(i)  # Add the values after each iteration to the list
print(lst)
```

Comment: Your variable is `lst` but you're printing `list`