# how to store arrays inside tuple in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tuples

I have a simple question in python. How can I store arrays inside a tuple in Python. For example:

I want the output of my code to be like this:

```
bnds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

So I want `(0, 1)` to be repeated for a specific number of times inside a tuple!

I have tried to use the following code to loop over a tuple:

```
g = (())
for i in range(4):
    b1 = (0,1) * (i)
    g = (g) + (b1)
print(g)
```

However, the output is :

```
(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

Maybe this is a simple question but I am still beginner in python!

Any help!

Comment: `((0, 1),) * 4`?

Comment: Tuples are immutable. check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309329/inserting-an-item-in-a-tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a list, fill it up, then convert it to a tuple.

```
g = []
b1 = (0, 1)

for i in range(4):
    g.append(b1)
g = tuple(g)
print(g)
```

There are cleaner ways to do it, but I wanted to adapt your code in order to help you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

```
>>> result =tuple((0,1) for _ in range(4))
>>> result 
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is this one:

`g = tuple((0,1) for i in range(4))`

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the items in tuple. Create g as a list then convert it into a tuple.

```
g = []
for i in range(4):
    b1 = (0,1) * (i)
    g .append(b1)
g = tuple(g)
```

Using list comprehension makes the code faster :

```
g = tuple([(0,1)*i for i in range(4)])
```

To get the output asked:

```
g = tuple([(0,1) for i in range(4)])
```